# alignment issue between search box and search button

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to build a search page and alignment is correct between search box and search button in all browsers except internet explorer. The css codes used is

```
#srchBox {height:25px;width:400px;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:5px;}

#srchBtn{height:32px; width:100px; vertical-align:middle;}
```

It's alright in firefox and chrome..

Comment: please push your code for better understanding

Comment: Thr is nthing more ...jst and input type with type text and button..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see that:

tested in IE9, FF8 and Chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color:#DDDDDD">
        <input type="text"><input type="button" value="search">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if u wanna set the WIDTH of the textbox, just use size="30"

g.r.

Comment: border:1px;
 border-radius:5px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px;

Comment: what u mean with rounded edges ? a button has already rounded edges, excepting in windows 2000 XD
as i know the style of the "standard" <input type="button"/> is just a matter of the OS. like on MAC, the buttons and textfields r displayed differently to windows.

Comment: @Sam
moz-border is the property of mozila it dosnt work in ie.

Answer (score 0):

u set the vertical align 4 all CHILDS of srchBtn.
try to put srchBox & srchBtn in a div and give the div element the vertical align.

hope that's the issue

otherwhise try vertical-align:baseline

Answer (score 0):

Try float:left on both elements. You may need to set the margin to 0.